# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List in asp mvc

Tags: c#, string, linq, generics

i need join 4 tabel with Linq . but it show me this error :

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List' E:\MyProject\GoKhoda\GoKhoda\Areas\Classes\StudentsFunc.cs  20  20  GoKhoda

this is my code :

```
public List<Tbl_Students> ShowAllStudents()
    {
        var qstudent = from s in _db.Tbl_Students
                       join pr in _db.Tbl_Pye_Reshte on s.StudentID equals pr.StudentID
                       join r in _db.Tbl_Reshte on pr.ReshteID equals r.ReshteID
                       join p in _db.Tbl_Paye on pr.PayeID equals p.PayeID
                       orderby p.PayeID descending
                       select new { StudentName = s.StudentName, StudentFamily = s.StudentFamily, StudentImage = s.StudentImage, StudentPayeName = p.PayeName, StudentReshtName = r.ReshteName };
        return qstudent.ToList();
    }
```

Why Show Me Error ? How can i solve this ?

Comment: The exception doesn't tell much less than we can tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var qstudent = from s in _db.Tbl_Students
    join pr in _db.Tbl_Pye_Reshte on s.StudentID equals pr.StudentID
    join r in _db.Tbl_Reshte on pr.ReshteID equals r.ReshteID
    join p in _db.Tbl_Paye on pr.PayeID equals p.PayeID
    orderby p.PayeID descending
    select new Tbl_Students { StudentName = s.StudentName, StudentFamily = s.StudentFamily, StudentImage = s.StudentImage, StudentPayeName = p.PayeName, StudentReshtName = r.ReshteName };
return qstudent.ToList();
```

`Select new { ... }` will just create an anonymous type whch can´t be converted to *anything* except `object`.

Just as an aside: you should consider naming your types depending on what an entity is within your application, in your example `Student`, not the table where the entity is stored.

Answer (score 1):

The issue it that anonymous type is a return type from your LINQ query. This anonymous type is defined by compiler based on the names and types specified in the select new {} statement.

To fix it, you can define a new type Student

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string StudentFamily { get; set; }
    public byte[] StudentImage { get; set; }
    public string StudentPayeName { get; set; }
    public string StudentReshtName { get; set; }
}
```

and then use Student type in LINQ's select statement and as return type for the ShowAllStudents method

```
public List<Student> ShowAllStudents()
{
    var qstudent = from s in _db.Tbl_Students
                   join pr in _db.Tbl_Pye_Reshte on s.StudentID equals pr.StudentID
                   join r in _db.Tbl_Reshte on pr.ReshteID equals r.ReshteID
                   join p in _db.Tbl_Paye on pr.PayeID equals p.PayeID
                   orderby p.PayeID descending
                   select new Student { StudentName = s.StudentName, StudentFamily = s.StudentFamily, StudentImage = s.StudentImage, StudentPayeName = p.PayeName, StudentReshtName = r.ReshteName };
    return qstudent.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an anonymous object use your model class in `select`. Then you can return `List<StudentModel>` instead of `List<object>`.